# VIM auto command runs first command but not the commands after pipes

Tags: vim

I have this auto command which runs when I exit out of command mode. But for some reason it doesn't convert the tabs to spaces as intended. I have to run it manually. Any ideas why?

```
augroup write_it
    autocmd!
    autocmd InsertLeave * write | set et | retab | :%s/\s\+$//e
    autocmd CursorHold * up
augroup END
```

Comment: Your autocmd is working fine for me; you can `:set verbose=20` to check what's executed, or append a `| echomsg 'DONE'` at the end.